Facing issue with Jenkins swarm plugin
I am trying to register a Jenkins slave using swarm-client.jar file but I am facing the "SEVERE: Could not obtain CSRF crumb. Response code: 400" error.
I am using swarm-plugin version 3.42 and trying to access jenkins master on http on port 80.
Any pointer is highly appreciated.
Thanks
